# How to stop child Linearlayout to overlap parent Linearlayout rounded corners?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout which is parent layout, it has rounded corners. Inside this parent layout there is child Linearlayout which has sharp corners. Now the problem is that child Linearlayout is overlapping the parent Linearlayout's rounded corners. I know we can fix this by giving rounded corners to the child parent as well. But i need an alternative way. How can we fix it ? Here is the code i have tried

```
    <!-- HorizontalLinearStart   -->   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/whiteroundedbg"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:elevation="4dp">


  





    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:background="#ededed">

       







    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout><!-- HorizontalLinearEnd   -->
```

Comment: maybe you should try to give margin to your inner linear layout not the outer one

Comment: instead of layout margin, use padding.

Comment: I need the child layout to be attached on all sides. So there is no chance of margin and padding . Thanks for comment

Comment: if you have a round corner, you have to use a small padding, like 2dp and it will work... otherwise remove your linear layout and use card view... (cardview add padding behind the sene...)

Comment: As I understood, you need container with rounded corners and with possibility to Clip children corners. You can check https://github.com/venator85/RoundClippingLayout as string point

Comment: @user13926345 i added my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just swap this content of two  linearlayout:-

```
<!-- HorizontalLinearStart   -->
<LinearLayout

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:background="#ededed"


xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:elevation="4dp">
</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTE:-keep both height and width of linear layout same**

method 2

**or why not using views instead of viewgroup**

example:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView android:clipToPadding="true"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



        <ImageView
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:id="@+id/customProfileGridImg"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:paddingBottom="100dp"
            android:paddingTop="100dp"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: This answer lacks context.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in code if you're on API level 21 and above using

```
outerLayout.setOutlineProvider(ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND);
outerLayout.setClipToOutline(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

In your child linear layout add margin using the following syntax:

```
android:layout_margin="24dp"
```

You should replace the margin dp value with your own value so that it gives the desired result.

Comment: I need the child layout to be attached on all sides. So there is no chance of margin and padding .

Comment: please clarify this in the question too

Comment: also please add images of how your current layout looks like and a rough pencil sketch of layout that you wish to achieve.